# How to type letters in floral form in word using latex command?

Tags: methods, ms-word, latex, office365, equation

I'm inputing equations in word 2019. I like to use latex command to input equation in word. But I can't type floral letter using latex, **\mathbb()**

What I did is as follows.
First, I click **alt** and **option** key at the same time. Second, I type "\mathbb(N)", but I didn't get the N in floral form.

I don't know the reason. Did I use wrong latex code? Could you help me with some latex code that can produce a correct result?

I have an alternative method. First, I type the equation using "Typora". Second, I convert the markdown file to word format. Then, I can get the floral form of alphabets. But it is wasteful. Would you like to give me some good suggestions?

Comment: \mathbb is defined in the amsfont package. Without this package, it is an undefined command. But I do not know how to tell word to use it..

Comment: @AlainMerigot I have an alternative method. First, I type the equation using "Typora". Second, I convert the markdown file to word format. Then, I can get the floral form of alphabets. But it is wasteful.